# Arch Linux: 'whatprovides' equivalent option for pacman

Tags: linux, package-management, arch-linux

I've come from Fedora and am trying out Arch Linux.

I was wondering if the packager 'pacman' contains functionality like that provided by 'yum whatprovides':

```
provides or whatprovides
              Is  used  to  find out which package provides some feature or file. Just use a specific name or a file-
              glob-syntax wildcards to list the packages available or installed that provide that feature or file.
```

Comment: Not sure if you still use Arch, but you might consider changing the accepted answer to one of the other two answers since this is now built in to `pacman`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pacman -F file_name` for Pacman v5.2.1 - libalpm v12.0.1

Comment: Don’t forget to run `pacman -Fy` as root prior to running this command to download fresh package databases from the server.

Comment: Perhaps better to just use `pacman -Fy file_name` as recommended in [VasyaNovikov's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1131350/1210833), at least if you use it infrequently.  After the first use, of course, you can resort to `pacman -F file_name`, but as @tukusejssirs noted, you should still update the database every so often.

Answer (score 12):

I believe pkgfile  or pkgfile -s are what you're looking for.  For further reference I will direct you [to here.](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta) The link will show you what other commands you might need a translation for.  I hope it helps.

Comment: and for local installed packages should be pkgfile -U

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `pacman -Fy file_name`, as suggested in [this Unix & Linux Stack answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14865/92541).